# Adobe AIR application audio

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, streaming, air

I have a quick question relating to Actionscript 3 / AIR. I have looked through the site, but may be searching for the wrong thing or terms.

Is it possible to get an application wide audio stream from an AIR application?

I am trying to create a local audio file containing everything (all channels) played in an AIR app.

Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Kind regards,

Phil

---

Update:

I have tried using the SoundMixer.computeSpectrum() function, but it returns a bytearray (size 2480) full of zeros...

It looks like it isn't reading the audio data correctly... I am playing a swf loaded using a SwfLoader and it is playing the sound out...

Odd... Anybody got an idea..?

Comment: I have an AIR app that loads and plays several audio and video clips... I am trying to record all the audio that is played to one file... I am trying to find the 'master' audio stream that I can then record to an aduio file... Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

There is [SoundMixer.computeSpectrum](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29), which will give you the global waveform or frequency data for the app. Unfortunately, it is fairly unreliable, and if you are trying to piece together the entire accurate audio stream, it is probably insufficient. But it might be enough to suit your needs if you are making, say, a visualizer or something else that only wants to know the current state of the audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SoundMixer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) Class? It has a computeSpectrum method that can get all playing sounds into a ByteArray, if I'm not totally misinterpreting the docs there.